# Ошибка - context must be a dict rather than RequestContext

Tags: python, django

Только начинаю изучение django. Вылезла такая ошибка  context must be a dict rather than RequestContext.

views.py :

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Изучайте, видимо, по давно устаревшим инструкциям. RequestContext уже года 4 как не используется.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev в документации Django 1.9 он всё ещё предлагается к использованию, однако

Comment: @andreymal и даже эта документация устарела уже на два года.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev на https://djbook.ru такой туториал лежит. Так как можно это исправить ?)

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов так как написано в ошибке - использовать словарь вместо `RequestContext`.

Comment: ой, действительно) А не знаете ли какие нибудь годные туториалы или курсы, если не сложно)

Comment: @АртёмМолчанов оригинальная документация Django на английском, например)

Answer (score 1):

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Просто убрать RequestContex